# UITableview edit/done button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a tableview and navigation bar on the top.

I have a Edit button on the left of my navigation bar with the following line of code.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

When i click on the edit button, it changes to done button. All is fine so far.

Where do i add code, if i want to do a small operation when the Done button is clicked.?

Comment: Would you consider properly setting the correct answer?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The button stops committing the changes to your controller class once you override it's default action with `self.editButtonItem.action = @selector(editClicked:);`

What you should do is override UIViewController's setEditing method in your own controller class:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing == YES) 
    {
        // Your code for entering edit mode goes here
    } else {
        // Your code for exiting edit mode goes here
    }
}
```

You also need to set your UIBarButtonItem to "Edit" in storyboard or if you prefer doing it in code use the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

editButtonItem is a helper property already set by the system for your comfort.

Comment: Thanks. Even easier, I did `-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated { [super setEditing:editing animated:animated]; [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];}`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Swift version I used:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if editing {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

thats what i did on Swift 4:

this is create bar button in viewDidLoad():

```
// init barbutton and set default to true
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    super.isEditing = true
```

add override setEditing() below the viewDidLoad():

```
    override func setEditing (_ editing:Bool, animated:Bool)
{
    super.setEditing(editing,animated:animated)
    if(self.isEditing)
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = "Edit"
    }else
    {
        self.editButtonItem.title = "Done"
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit and Done label must be reversed and super.isEditing = false